# How to get forum for EE v2.10.1

Tags: forum

I am using EE v2.10.1  licence & need to add the forum addon but did not get any option as default.
I also have EE v3.0.4.

Pleas advise.

Thanks

Comment: You should contact EllisLab directly, as forum seems to be not available for sale separately anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact sales@ellislab.com